# How to make a python tkinter app work on android

Tags: python, android, tkinter, apk

Im trying to make a tkinter app that works fine on my pc work on my phone.

So far i have tried nothing (apart from a google search). I am new to android app dev but not new to python.

FYI this app is to count the amount of cars, motor bikes and lorries that go past.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = Tk()
root.title('Counter')


def caradd():
    caraddf = open('results.txt', 'a')
    caraddf.writelines('Car\n')
    caraddf.close()

def mbikeadd():
    mbikeaddf = open('results.txt', 'a')
    mbikeaddf.writelines('MotorBike\n')
    mbikeaddf.close()

def Lorryadd():
    Lorryaddf = open('results.txt', 'a')
    Lorryaddf.writelines('Lorry\n')
    Lorryaddf.close()

carframe = Frame(root, bg='red')
carframe.pack()

cartitle = Label(carframe, bg='red', fg='white', text='\nCar\n')
cartitle.pack(side=LEFT)

carbutton = Button(carframe,  bg='red', fg='white', text='\nCar +1\n', command = caradd)
carbutton.pack()

######################################################################

mbikeframe = Frame(root)
mbikeframe.pack()

mbiketitle = Label(mbikeframe, text='\nMotorbike\n')
mbiketitle.pack(side=LEFT)

mbikebutton = Button(mbikeframe, text='\nMotorbike +1\n', command = mbikeadd)
mbikebutton.pack()

######################################################################

Lorryframe = Frame(root)
Lorryframe.pack()

Lorrytitle = Label(Lorryframe, bg='yellow', text='\nLorry\n')
Lorrytitle.pack(side=LEFT)

Lorrybutton = Button(Lorryframe, bg='yellow', text='\nLorry +1\n', command = Lorryadd)
Lorrybutton.pack()
```

Should work like windows on android

Answer (score 2):

to run a tkinter program (or any Python program) on Android, you should use the app Pydroid 3 (on the play store), which has a modified tkinter module for Android and much more. To install this module, go in the app's menu > pip > quick install > tkinter .

Answer (score 1):

You Cannot Export APK With Tkinter , Use Kivy ...

In Kivy , You can Only first Write Source and Export For All Platform ( This Is Cross-platform)